# PHP RegEx when strange char is included data not found

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract data from html using regex:

the html content:

```
<td height="19" align="left" class="title">Multiple Adapters, with Two Necks one vertical &amp; one at 45°</td>
```

the php and regex:

```
preg_match_all('%<td height="19" align="left" class="title">(.*?)</td>%sim', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$title = trim($matches[0][1]);
```

charset is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

This is the only case when the data is not found;

Why is the data not found?

Comment: What encoding html content has?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_match_all('%<td height="19" align="left" class="title">(.*?)</td>%simu', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

As wrote [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) u - modifier for UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to just encode the data before using `preg_match`:

`$content = utf8_encode($content)`

Comment: The degree sign was probably Latin-1, and thus an invalid UTF-8 character.